# После привязки карты на google maps platform выбивает ошибку?

Tags: google-maps, карты

перехожу на https://mapsplatform.google.com меня сразу перекидывает на страницу привязки банковской карты я указываю все что надо нажимаю дальше и мне выскакивает ошибка
[image: скрин]